# Repository Pattern without Edit

Tags: c#, repository

I am reading about the Repository Pattern in C#. Every article I read with a sample repository looks like below and does not contain a definition for Edit entity.

```
    TEntity Get(TKey id);
    void Save(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
```

Is it bad idea to have Edit method in base repository interface like below?

```
   public interface IRepositor<T>
    {
        void Edit(Predicate<T> predicate, Action<T> action);
    } 




  public class Car : IRepository<Car>
    {
        public void Edit(Predicate<Car> predicate, Action<Car> action)
        {
            var car = Context.Cars.SingleOrDefault(x => predicate(x));

            if(car == null) throw new Exception("Not found");

            action.Invoke(car);



        }
    }

public class CarController
{
    public void Edit(CarViewModel vm)
    {
        carService.Edit(x => x.Id == vm.Id, y => y.Type == "BMW" );
    }
}
```